How do I configure kakoune to indent in insert mode
I'd like to be able to indent in insert mode.  I want spaces not tabs.
I have this in my kakrc file
map global insert <c-gt> '<esc><gt>i'
But this does not work.

I was just trying to figure out the same thing and I ended up with this:
map global insert <c-d> %{<a-;>: execute-keys -draft <lt><ret>}
map global insert <c-t> %{<a-;>: execute-keys -draft <gt><ret>}

The a-; command places kakoune into normal mode for a single command, and we then run the execute-keys command to perform the desired action (indent or outdent).
(I'm using c-d and c-t here, since I'm coming from vim.)
